# Read separate parts of an XDocument

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to printout on a WebPage with asp.net, just separate parts of a XDocument file.

For example: I have a resume (CV) file and I want to printout only the part  of "Work experience". 
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You Can use LINQ to XML to extract the part you want from your XDocument

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the node/s  inside the XDocument you can get it with:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("path.xml");
var query = dox.Root.Descendants("Work experience");
```

This will get you 0-n nodes named "Work experience".

**iterate over all nodes:**

```
foreach(var exp in query)
    // do something with the xml node
```

Comment: I've added some code. But without any more informations (what is a CV file, what structure has the xml file) I can't help you anymore.

Comment: http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu/TechnicalResources/XML/xsd/europass_XML-schema-v2.0-description.pdf